# Configure Azure SQL DTU with Entity Framework Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I would like to know if it is possible to define the **DTU** of a **Azure SQL database** when using **Entity Framework Code First**? What i mean is, you can use DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges-DropCreateDatabaseAlways, but each time it is dropped and re created, it gets the **Standard DTU** by default but it needs to be the **Basic DTU**.

**This is what i mean:**
[image]

Any way of achieving this either with entity framework configuration or another approach?
**Thank you** in advance for any feedback!
Kind regards

Comment: Check this link https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-an-Azure-SQL-dbd0bf6a/sourcecode?fileId=145776&pathId=1349541144

Comment: Will check and test this out, looks interesting, i will see if i can combine this along using Entity Framework. Will post an update this week. (Thank you so far!)

Comment: Hi @Llazar, this seems to be what i need but i can't make it work, issues with the "clientId" that is not found, i will try later on to register the App (i tried with a registered app but this didn't work neither ...). Thank you, you can post this as answer if you like so i can mark it as one ;)

Comment: With clientId they used to authenticate with AAD but you don't  include it your solution if doesn't needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Azure Sql database programmatically in C#. You can add almost everything from recourse grup, server, database. There is different way that you can do it but I have used the code from [this sample from Microsoft OneCode team](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-create-an-Azure-SQL-dbd0bf6a/sourcecode?fileId=145776&pathId=1349541144). Is not the code that can complete all your task but is a god starting point to achieve it.

Comment: Thank you again, very useful!

Comment: Glad that solution helpt you.